# Print a two dimensional array in an outward spiral

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

Given an (N X M)array, say:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Print its elements as if it was traversed spirally from the centre.
In the above case, the answer would be

```
5 4 7 8 9 6 3 2 1
```

Being familiar with printing an array in an inward spiral, I suggested stacking the elements and popping them later, but I was told to do it otherwise.

Note : N is not always equal to M

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What is the code snippet that will give such an output?

Comment: @cabellicar123 this question is unclear and not a good fit for Programmers as written. Before suggesting someone post at a different SE site, please be familiar with its help center and community guidelines. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Can you add an output example in the on-square matrix case?

Answer (score 2):

Given a NxN matrix (being N an odd number), and starting at the center position [N/2, N/2], the general path to generate the spiral is:

```
move  left      1      position
move  down      1      position
move right from 1 to 2 positions
move    up from 1 to 2 positions
move  left from 1 to 3 positions
move  down from 1 to 3 positions
move right from 1 to 4 positions
move    up from 1 to 4 positions
...
```

There is a pattern you can follow.

**Edit after edition of OP's question**

If the matrix is NxM with `N != M` or N or M are even, first you have to clarify in your question what is the behavior you expect when you reach one of the edges of the matrix: stop? go on ignoring the positions outside the matrix?

Comment: How do you determine the center for N x M matrix?

Comment: The center of a N x M matrix is in [N/2, M/2], but if M is even, you may also set the center in M/2+1, because there is not a symmetric center.
Also note that you have to change the algorithm slightly if N != M, because you are not going to reach the edge of the matrix at the same time.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger - the same problem arrises when N is even. The question is ONLY defined for N == M & N is ODD.

Comment: Yes, that was the initial OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I use Swift 2.0 to implement it but it is very C-like:

```
// the function returns the elements from an inward spiral which is then printed in reverse
// array has to be 2 dimensional; returns one-dimensional array of elements
func spiralElements<T>(array: [[T]]) -> [T] {
    // point which gets accessed
    var x = 0
    var y = 0

    // directions in x and y
    var dx = 1
    var dy = 0

    // bounds which get constrained further during the execution
    var xMin = 0
    var xMax = array.count - 1 // x dimension index
    var yMin = 0
    var yMax = array[0].count - 1 // y dimension index

    // a list which can be appended to
    var result = [T]()

    // loops exactly numberOfElements times of the whole array
    // x dimension count * y dimension count
    for _ in 1...(array.count * array[0].count) {
        result.append(array[x][y])

        // if future point is not inside bounds
        if !(xMin <= x + dx && x + dx <= xMax && yMin <= y + dy && y + dy <= yMax) {

            // go left
            if dy == 0 {
                dy = dx
                dx = 0
            } else {
                dx = -dy
                dy = 0
            }

            // constrain the bounds (depending on the direction)
            if dy == -1 {
                yMax--
            } else if dy == 1 {
                yMin++
            } else if dx == -1 {
                xMax--
            } else if dx == 1 {
                xMin++
            }
        }

        x += dx
        y += dy
    }

    return result
}

// calculate elements
var spiralElementsOfArray = spiralElements(...)

// printing
for var i = spiralElementsOfArray.count - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
    print(spiralElementsOfArray[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This naive javascript version will always walk the standard spiral, it will ignore out-of-bounds and keep going until all elements have been visited.

```
function spiral(arr, rows, cols) {
    if(rows <= 0 || cols <= 0) throw Error("Invalid Argument(s)");
    var result = [];
    var count = rows * cols;
    var col = Math.floor(cols / 2);
    var row = Math.floor(rows / 2) + ((rows & 1) == 0 ? -1 : 0);
    var vertLvl = 1;
    var horLvl = 1;
    var vertDir = 1;
    var horDir = -1;
    var i, v;
    result.push(arr[row][col]);
    count--;
    while(count > 0) {
        for(i=0; i < horLvl; i++) {
            col += horDir;
            if(row < 0 || row >= rows || col < 0 || col >= cols) { continue; }
            v = arr[row][col];
            count--; 
            result.push(v);
        }
        horDir *= -1; horLvl++;
        if(count <= 0) { break; }
        for(i=0; i < vertLvl; i++) {
            row += vertDir;
            if(row < 0 || row >= rows || col < 0 || col >= cols) { continue; }
            v = arr[row][col];
            count--; 
            result.push(v);
        }
        vertDir *= -1; vertLvl++;
        if(count <= 0) { break; }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(spiral( [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], 3, 3 ) );
console.log(spiral( [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]], 4, 3 ) );
console.log(spiral( [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]], 3, 4 ) );
console.log(spiral( [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]], 4, 4 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the matrix is N by N with N odd (so it has a central element), and we will call the central element e[n][n] - using row column.

Then we basically print by drawing squares. I will assume that we start in the top left as its a bit easier. I.e. print 1 in the output after 5 in your example.

So you print e[n][n], for the square at level p e[n-p][n-p], and traverse laterally to e[n-p][n+p], then traverse vertically to e[n+p][n+p] and so on round the square. When you get back to e[n-p-1][n-p], do p++ and start again until you hit the edge. You can obviously start in different places than a corner, but it doesnt matter much. For N even you just need to use some floor/ceiling functiosn appropriately do deal with the fact that there is no central element.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pixelscan/0.1.0) is an implementation I wrote to scan a raster of points in a ring pattern. You can invoke the function using radii 0, 1, 2, etc, and it will give you the indices you want. You can then use those indices to access and print the element values.